# React router not rendering default component in AWS cloudfront but works fine in local dev

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront

This is the router component I'm using. I am deploying the build-in AWS S3 and accessing through CloudFront.

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={IndexView} />
                <Route path="/home" component={HomeView} />
                <Route path="/index" component={IndexView} />
                <Route path="/page1" component={PageView} />
                <Route component={IndexView} />
            </Switch>
```

When I run the build-in local using an HTTP server and call the index.html, it gets routed to IndexView. The URL gets appended with few query string values but matches the route path.

starting page
http://localhost:3000/index.html?Param1=test
Gets updated to
http://localhost:3000/index#Param1=test
Redirects to
http://localhost:3000/index

But when deployed in AWS CloudFront, the index view is loading partially(initial logs in the file are logged in the window console) and returns with a 404 error. The loading happens until the first few functions are called and the URL is updated.
starting page
https://cloudURL/index.html?Param1=test
Gets updated to
https://cloudURL/index#Param1=test
doesn't get redirected, but a 404 error is logged in the console window for the URL
**https://cloudURL/index**

I have enabled the permission in S3 and the bucket hosting. Given the index and error page as index.html.

When I am specifying the default component, the index.html page loads and returns a white page and when I manually update the URL with /index, it gets redirected to index view.